# C# WPF Datacontext Binding dynamic Elements

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, data-binding, datacontext

I have a stackpanel that is filled with dynamic editors. The values inside the editors (TextBoxes, DatePickers, etc) are based on a item from a listbox. I create these editors based on the class and its properties bound to the listbox.

The "rendered" XAML code would something like this:

```
<StackPanel Name="LeftEditorStack">
    <StackPanel Name="OuterPanelFirstname">
        <RadioButton Name="FirstnameEnabled"></RadioButton>

        <!--or any other possible FrameWorkElement-->
        <TextBox></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

The `TextBox` has a databinding that is bound in code behind.

```
editorBinding = new Binding();
editorBinding.Path = new PropertyPath(String.Format("DataContext.{0}", properties[i].Name));
editorBinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource() { Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, AncestorType = typeof(StackPanel), AncestorLevel = 1 };
//editorAttribute is a custom Attribute that contains some information about the type of the Editor, BindingProperty, Position, Size and other stuff
editor.SetBinding(editorAttribute.BindingProperty, editorBinding);
```

This means the Datacontext of the `LeftEditorStack` is the real source for the binding of the `TextBox`. This works fine, but when I change the `DataContext` of the `LeftEditorStack` the `TextBox` does not get the update. The Update is occurs inside of a `SelectionChanged` Event:

```
private void lb_left_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.LeftEditorStack.DataContext = null;
    this.LeftEditorStack.DataContext = this.lb_left.SelectedItem;
}
```

How can I get the `TextBox` to change its value when the `DataContext` is updated? I can not use `UpdateTarget` from the `BindingExpression` because the usercontrol that contains my editors has no direct access to the dynamic editors.
Also setting the `BindingMode` or the `UpdateSourceTrigger` did not change this behaviour.

**Update**
As Grx70 pointed out my `AncestorLevel` was wrong. After I set the `AncestorLevel` to 2 it works fine.

Comment: Actually, since you set `AncestorLevel = 1` on your binding, the data context of `OuterPanelFirstname` is the source for the binding, which is inherited from `LeftEditorStack` unless it's explicitly set - are you sure it's never the case?

Comment: That's a point, I'll try to change this to `AncestorLevel = 2`, the basic structure stais the same for all editors.

Comment: Thanks, the `AncestorLevel = 2` solved my Problem